# I have a magento website elizona.in it is not loading properly in uc mobile browser. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento-1.9

I have a magento 1.9 website elizona.in
It is loading and working properly in all browsers except UC Mobile Browser.
I am not able to find what is the problem. Please provide me a instant solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser issue, wait until the next update, or write to browser support. It's quite common to have issues on less popular browsers.